# how to transform a List<Map<Customer, Map<key, BigDecimal>>> into a Map<Customer, Map<key, BigDecimal>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm stuck with a java8 stream problem.
I've got a

```
List<Map<Customer, Map<key, BigDecimal>>>
```

that i want to transform into a

```
Map<Customer, Map<key, BigDecimal>>
```

where the key is the month and the BigDecimal is the sum of the BigDecimals.

I can do it by iterations, but i wanted to use java8 streams as I think it should be possible.
When I iterate, I'm using a temporary

```
Map<Customer, List<Map<key, BigDecimal>>>
```

that I reduce by iteration on each customer.

but to do it with stream, i'm stuck to add the element to the temporary list !

could someone help ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could sort that by doing

```
    private static final BinaryOperator<FactureMensuel> applatirListeFactureMensuelle = new BinaryOperator<FactureMensuel>() {
        @Override
        public FactureMensuel apply(FactureMensuel factureMensuel, FactureMensuel factureMensuel2) {
            factureMensuel2.forEach((k, v) -> factureMensuel.merge(k, v, BigDecimal::add));
            return factureMensuel;
        }
    };



oemInvoices.stream()
    .reduce((oemInvoice1, oemInvoice2) -> {
        oemInvoice2.forEach((k, v) -> oemInvoice1.merge(k, v, applatirListeFactureMensuelle));
        return oemInvoice1;
    }).get();
```

Which is usinf forEach on the map to merge both maps

Comment: You asked for a stream solution rather than an operation that mutates the original maps.

Answer (score 2):

In java 9, we will be getting `flatMapping` collector ([see here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-February/031218.html)) that will make this sort of thing simpler.

You can backport the code for `flatMapping` into your project and when java 9 hits, replace the static import with the official one.  It would look something like this:

```
public static <T, U, A, R>
    Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(
        Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
        Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream
    ) {
        BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
        return Collector.of(
            downstream.supplier(),
            (r, t) -> {
                try (Stream<? extends U> result = mapper.apply(t)) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        result.sequential()
                        .forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, u));
                    }
                }
            },
            downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0])
        );
    }
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
Map<Customer, Map<key, BigDecimal>> result = input.stream()
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(
            e->e.getKey(),
            flatMapping(
                e->e.getValue().entrySet().stream(), 
                toMap(e->e.getKey(), e->e.getValue(), BigDecimal::add)
            )
        ));
```

If you don't want to do this and would prefer to use the currently standard collectors, you can use use the 3-parameter `toMap`, which combines map and reduce:

```
Map<Customer, Map<key, BigDecimal>> result = input.stream()
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(toMap(
            e->e.getKey(),
            e->e.getValue(),
            (a,b) -> Stream.of(a,b)   // merge the 2 maps
                    .map(Map::entrySet)
                    .flatMap(Set::stream)
                    .collect(toMap(
                        e->e.getKey(),
                        e->e.getValue(), 
                        BigDecimal::add
                    ))
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

What’s missing in the API is a function for merging two entire `Map`s (though the method for merging a single mapping exists). With a little helper function for creating such a `Collector`

```
static <K,V> Collector<Map<K,V>,?,Map<K,V>> mergeMaps(BinaryOperator<V> op) {
    return Collector.of(()->new HashMap<>(),
        (m,n)->  n.forEach((k,v)->m.merge(k, v, op)),
        (m,n)->{ n.forEach((k,v)->m.merge(k, v, op)); return m; });
}
```

you can solve your task like

```
Map<Customer, Map<Key, BigDecimal>> collected =
    list.stream().flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, mergeMaps(BigDecimal::add))));
```

Comment: Very nice. Yes, there's `Map.putAll` and `Map.replaceAll` but no `Map.mergeAll`. See [JDK-8072718](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072718). It might get into 9....